# Dynamics SqlDataDictionaryPermission failure

Tags: axapta, x++

I am trying to truncate one of our tables in a class to run as a batch job, but keep getting a "Request for permission of type SqlDataDictionaryPermission failed. This is on an AX 4.0 system. I followed MSDN example on acquiring permissions and I am an admin. Here's the code:

```
   //Truncate table    
   new SqlDataDictionaryPermission(    
               methodstr(SqlDataDictionary, tableTruncate)).assert();    
   sqlDict = new SqlDataDictionary();    
   sqlDict.tableTruncate(tableNum(PMF_INVENTTABLEMODULELOG),false);    
   CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
```

As I stated, I have admin access to this, so should have the required security key. Though this is displaying the (usr) environment in the class list.

Comment: Try using the delete_from operator.  Not sure if it gets 'downgraded', however, due to associated delete actions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is running server side?

You did not expose your method definition.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this issue in Ax 2009, while trying to set up a batch that reindexes tables from parameters.

The method doesn't need to be static or have server predicate. The only thing that works is setting the class "RunOn" parameter as "Server".

I know it's and old question with low views, but perhaps some poor soul can be saved.